# Eclipse - Wrong project name when importing maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven-2

I'm using eclipse mars and I'm working on a multi modules maven 2 project.

Since now it was always working fine when importing the project into eclispe.

My project structure is like

```
myproject
|-common
|-dao
|- ...
```

In each pom the artifact-id is

```
<artifactId>myproject-common</artifactId>
<artifactId>myproject-dao</artifactId>
...
```

What I always did till now

- retrieve the project from svn
- mvn clean install
- mvn eclispe:eclipse
- in eclipse import > existing project > browse to myproject and it displays the good project names : `myproject-common`, `myproject-dao`, ...

But since today the last step gives me the folder name in place of the artifact name : `common`, `dao`, ...

And after import, lot of errors saying eg. that `Project 'dao' is missing required Java Project: 'myproject-common'`

I don't understand.  Same version of eclispe,maven and java than few months ago.

And after mvn eclipse:eclispe, the .project file is containing the good name

```
<projectDescription>
  <name>myproject-common</name>
```

How can I solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing:
    import > existing project

to:
    Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects

Comment: interesting, import existing maven projects gives me wrong project names corresponding to folder names, not artifact ids